# regexp in php doesn't work for @\\section{(.*?)}@U

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a simple regex-script in PHP:

```
<?php  
$string = "\section{Test 1} 
sdfgsdfg";  
$regex = "@\\section{(.*?)}@U";  
$replace = "$1jksdfahlkjh";  
$newString = preg_replace ($regex, $replace, $string, -1 );  
?>
```

See: http://regexp-tester.mediacix.de/t287

using

```
echo $newString;
```

only give me

> \section{Test 1} sdfgsdfg

Regex-patterns like

```
$bbcode = array(

"/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is" => "<strong>$1</strong>",
"/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/is" => "<u>$1</u>",
"/\[url\=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is" => "<a href='$1'>$2</a>"

);
$text = "[b]Text[/b][u]Text[/u]";

$text = preg_replace(array_keys($bbcode), array_values($bbcode), $text);
echo $text;
```

works great. Is there any solution? I don't want to write an whole LaTeX-Parser, but I want to replace those "\section{...}"-Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `\`'s, because otherwise they will already be treated as an escape by php itself and then stripped:

```
$regexp = "@\\\\section{(.*)}@";
```

The `U` modifier is unnecessary, as that makes the `.*?` greedy again, so you are reversing the reversing. Just `.*` works just as well.